# Do I need a transit visa in India if my flight will transit in Mumbai and Delhi

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, india

My friend just bought Return Ticket JET AIR From Singapore to London, but on his itinerary, his flight will transit in Delhi and on his return Ticket it says it transits in Mumbai.

The question is: does he need a transit visa? Is his transit still in the same terminal in Delhi & Mumbai?

If He need one, How does he get it? Can he apply for one at the Airport?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What is your friend's citizenship?

Answer (score 1):

Transit visa is not required if your friend is not taking a domestic flight in India to reach his final destination - for e.g. if your friend's flight has a flight from Delhi to Mumbai - he would need to apply for a transit visa.

Your friend can stay in the waiting area for international passengers in case he is not taking a domestic flight to complete his journey.

Transit visa canbe applied with Indian high commission from Singapore in this case.